# How to hide an animated image on canvas?

Tags: wpf

I created an animated image to move on my canvas then I created another animated image ;

I want to hide just my first image after it's movement and before moving another;

I tried to set opacity of my drawing visual or image brush or etc zero;but all of my image

hide;

```
   List<EllipseGeometry> eg = new List<EllipseGeometry>();
            Path ballPath;
            int c = 0;
            foreach (Polyline p in pl)
            {
                if (p.Points.Count > 1)
                {

                    ballPath = new Path();

                    FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText("  " + (anl[c].DOffset).ToString() + "\n " + anl[c].playername + "  ", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
                    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                    new Typeface("arial"),
                   20,
                    Brushes.Black);

                    formattedText.MaxTextWidth = 500;
                    formattedText.MaxTextHeight = 500;
                    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
                    DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
                    drawingContext.DrawImage(il[c].Source, new Rect(4, 0, 26, 26));//30
                    drawingContext.DrawText(formattedText, new Point(1, 2));
                    drawingContext.Close();
                    RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace, (int)formattedText.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                    bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
                    ImageBrush b = new ImageBrush(bmp);
                    b.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                    ballPath.Fill = b;
                    mainwindow.animecan.Children.Add(ballPath);
                   ////
                    int jy = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < anl.Count; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (anl[i].offset == m)
                                jy = anl[i].offset;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    if (multi && p.Uid == jy.ToString())//اگر آفست مالتی اسپید شده باشه
                    {
                        eg.Add(new EllipseGeometry(ms[ih].p1, 27, 27));
                        ballPath.Data = eg.First();// animatedEllipseGeometry;
                        PathFigure myPathFigure = new PathFigure();
                        PointCollection pe = new PointCollection();
                        pe.Add(ms[ih].p1);
                        pe.Add(ms[ih].p2);
                        myPathFigure.StartPoint = eg.First().Center;
                        myPathFigure.Segments.Add(
                            new PolyLineSegment(pe, true));
                        PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
                        myPathGeometry.Figures.Add(myPathFigure);
                        myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
                        myPathGeometry.Figures.Add(myPathFigure);//
                        PointAnimationUsingPath centerPointAnimation1 = new PointAnimationUsingPath();
                        centerPointAnimation1.PathGeometry = myPathGeometry;
                        centerPointAnimation1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ms[ih].sspeed);
                        centerPointAnimation1.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ms[ih].delay);
                        centerPointAnimation1.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
                        eg.First().BeginAnimation(EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty, centerPointAnimation1);
                        eg.Remove(eg.First());
                    }
                    c++;
```

Comment: have you tried setting the image visibility to collapsed ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is caused because your whole code block is executed 'at once' (before updating the UI), rather than 'line by line'. In order to make your call to the `Visibility` property update before execution reaches the end of the code block, you'll need to queue it on the `Dispatcher` object. Try this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate
{
    yourControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
});
```